# How to add rows (so to have multi rows) bottom panel in gnome-session-flashback in ubuntu 14.04 32bit?

Tags: 14.04, panel, gnome-panel, resize

I'm experiencing Ubuntu 14.04LTS 32bit with gnome-session-flashback very, very useful for me! Just I need to double rows in bottom panel 'cause I use a lot of opened windows/apps but I really I don't know how do that!

I followed some guide and I modified pixel from 24 to 48 but It doesn't double the panel instead of bigger it and windows inside it. (I suppose this way works fine with some other DE not with gnome-session-flashback!!)

Any idea/suggestion please? A cold beer is ready to solver

Comment: Try asking on Gnome-Flashback mailing-list https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/gnome-flashback-list. But I think that feature was removed.